# Why am I getting QUnhandledException?

Tags: c++, face-recognition, openbr

- I am working on FaceRecognition project. For that i am using BRISK algorithm from openbr.
- For that i have to train data using many number of images. I am using training command as below,

  ```
  br -algorithm 'Open+Cvt(Gray)+Cascade(FrontalFace)+ASEFEyes+Affine(128,128,0.33,0.45)+  (Grid(10,10)+SIFTDescriptor(12)+ByRow)/(Blur(1.1)+Gamma(0.2)+DoG(1,2)+ContrastEq(0.1,10)+LBP(1,2)+RectRegions(8,8,6,6)+Hist(59))+PCA(0.95)+Normalize(L2)+Dup(12)+RndSubspace(0.05,1)+LDA(0.98)+Cat+PCA(0.95)+Normalize(L1)+Quantize:NegativeLogPlusOne(ByteL1)' -train ../data/ATT/img FaceRecognitionATT
  ```
- But i am getting '**QUnhandledException**' after sometime. I cant figure it out that why i am getting this error. I am using 13500 images for training.
- Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same error using OpenBR V1.1.0, with OpenCV-2.4.11 running on Ubuntu 14.04.3. I was able to move beyond the QUnhandledException by uninstalling QT4.x and explicitly linking OpenCV with QT5. With a little help from [this open GitHub issue](https://github.com/biometrics/openbr/issues/233), I got things working by doing the following.

Uninstall earlier version of QT:

```
apt-get remove qt4-linguist-tools
apt-get remove qt4-qmake
apt-get autoremove
```

Install QT5:

```
apt-get install qtdeclarative5-dev
apt-get install qttools5-dev-tools
```

Build OpenCV from source with this cmake command:

```
cmake -DWITH_QT5=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
```

Build OpenBR from source